# C static variable alternative for kotlin

Tags: kotlin

So in the recursion function in c we can use the "static" keyword for a variable that doesn't re-initialize upon recursive calls.

What is the static alternative for kotlin?

Comment: I know, I just said that to simplify. Anyway, I've removed that part if it were confusing.

Comment: Can't you use a parameter that doesn't change?

Comment: It can change, but not re-initialize upon recursive calls, ie hold the previous value. Not using global of course.

Comment: You have to declare a property outside the function for this. There is no equivalent to C static variables.

Comment: Note that ‘outside the function’ can still have restricted scope: it can be a top-level property that's local to the file, or a property of a non-public `object`. But those will still be common to all invocations of your recursive method, even if called from different threads (as would a C static). The robust, thread-safe way is to pass it as a parameter: it can have a default value, so that the top-level call doesn't need to pass it, and it can then be passed unchanged into recursive calls. If you need to share multiple values, wrap them in a ‘context’ object and pass that.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the `sequence` builder function can create something that can be called repeatedly or iterated and maintain some state between invocations. Not exactly the same, but some overlapping use cases with C statics.

Comment: @CyberAvater actually C static variables are global, their name is not in global scope, but effectively it is global variable